# SQL to Linq equivalent syntax

Tags: c#, sql, linq, unique

I need help to write linq syntax of below SQL query.

Business is: from table `PhoneNumberClick_Table`, I need to get `TotalCount`, `CountWithWhereCondition`, and `CountWithUniqueValue` datewise :

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT([ClickTime], 'yyyy-MM-dd') DateTimeField,
    COUNT (*) CountTotalClick,
    COUNT ((CASE PhoneNumber WHEN 'NotProvided' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)) CountNumberProvided,
    COUNT ((CASE PhoneNumber WHEN 'NotProvided' THEN NULL ELSE 1 END))  CountNumberNotProvided,
    COUNT (DISTINCT PhoneNumber) CountUniqueNumber
FROM 
    [dbo].[PhoneNumberClick_Table]
GROUP BY
    FORMAT([ClickTime], 'yyyy-MM-dd')
ORDER BY 
    FORMAT([ClickTime], 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use sum instead of count for case statement and your have to change the logic for phonenumber provided and not provided like my query

```
SELECT 
      FORMAT([ClickTime], 'yyyy-MM-dd') DateTimeField
     ,COUNT (*) CountTotalClick 
     ,sum((case when  PhoneNumber is not null then 1 else 0 end)) CountNumberProvided 
     ,sum((case when  PhoneNumber= 'NotProvided' then 0 else 1 end))  CountNumberNotProvided 
     ,COUNT (DISTINCT PhoneNumber) CountUniqueNumber
  FROM [dbo].[PhoneNumberClick_Table]
  GROUP by FORMAT([ClickTime], 'yyyy-MM-dd')
  ORDER BY FORMAT([ClickTime], 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Comment: actually my SQL is working fine. BUT i need to convert that into Linq syntax

Answer (score 0):

try using this [tool](http://www.sqltolinq.com/) , i used it before and worked great for me , for this tool to work best for you , try to segment your query and then sum them up after conversion